# A function in GAP to check if a graph is perfect

Tags: graph-theory, gap

I'm looking for a way to check if some graphs are [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph). GAP seems to be like the best way to do it, especially because I'm trying to do some things with groups at the same time. However, I haven't seen any function within GAP which would check perfectness of a graph. Does GAP have any such function?

I am familiar with the package GRAPE, as well as with AGT and Digraphs packages, but none of them seems to have this function built-in. Also, I am aware that GRAPE contains CliqueNumber and ChromaticNumber functions, and that I could use these two to check perfectness with a function of my own, but I'm still curious if that would be a necessary thing to do.

Comment: Checkout [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) and the function `is_perfect`. The GAP system is integrated in SageMath as well, so I think it might be a good choice for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of SageMath. I will check it out, it seems like it's going to work well for me!